# Edit Client in IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

The sample and seed data shows creating a new client in Startup.
This is fine in case of creating a client.
Are there any existing methods or provision for Updating a client. Update involves tracking the existing records from the collection fields within the clients too.
How are entities mapped from IdentityServer4.Models to IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities during an update considering the records are already available in database?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean when you say client?? If you mean Client for Identity server then you can edit/configure or add more clients or other resources in your config class. While startup, identity server will loads up all the clients by itself, all because of this code:

```
// Add identity server.

    services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetInMemoryIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetInMemoryApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetInMemoryClients(Configuration))
        .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
        .AddProfileService<SqlProfileService>();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any existing methods or provision for Updating a client.
>   Update involves tracking the existing records from the collection
>   fields within the clients too

Yes, you can update client as you can update any other data. Check [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html) how you can use EntityFramework core with identityserver4

> How are entities mapped from IdentityServer4.Models to
>   IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Entities during an update considering
>   the records are already available in database?

If you check the IdentityServer4 source you will find AutoMapper is used to convert entities (namespace **IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers**). And an extension named `ToModel` has been provided